# Staging Table Design for Performance

Tags: sqlperformance, azure-synapse

I have a typical star pattern in my Azure SQL Data Warehouse.  Data is first dumped into staging tables via Data Factory, then it calls a master procedure that calls other procedures to transform data into the appropriate format and then clear out the staging tables for that chunk of data.

Should these staging tables have indexes?  Should they have statistics?  I recently upgraded to Gen 2, but don't have auto create statistics turned on.  I worry that statistics will get created but not updated, and so will end up slowing things down more than anything.

For more context, there is a procedure to rebuild indexes and update statistics which is run overnight, once a day.  The data load process is run hourly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that these are staging tables, the biggest impacts will come from the following.

Where possible, use a hash distribution. This will give best performance when you process the table in subsequent steps. While documentation sometimes suggests round_robin distribution, and this is slightly faster for ingestion, the next query on the table will be slower.

Always use statistics. I suggest creating them manually, based on expected usage, for greater predictability in your ELT performance. If you don't create *and update* statistics you're going to get dreadful performance at some time in future. If you don't want to undertake the effort of manually managing statistics, then definitely turn on auto statistics.

Consider the use of HEAP vs CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE table structures for staging tables. In general, staging tables are processed on a whole-row basis, and you may find that your performance is better at the staging layer if you use a HEAP. This needs to be tested on your data, as the Gen2 caching that gives much greater performance does not apply to Heap tables.

Definitely create your fact and dimension tables as clustered columnstore indexes. Hash distribute your fact/s, and replicate your dimensions (unless you have billion row dimensions, in which case a hash distribution may be more appropriate).

If you're using CTAS algorithms your need for non-clustered indexes should be very low. I generally add indexes only when I see a performance problem with a query that I can't solve by any other technique.

Finally, make sure that you're using a reasonable DWU and Resource Class. A general rule of thumb is that you shouldn't be running your ELT at less than DWU500, and LARGERC. If you don't do this, you'll find that you get bad clustered columnstore indexes which will lead to future performance problems.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  I do want to clarify that the process steps are: 1. Load the data to staging tables, 2. Transform data and load into warehouse tables, and 3. Delete staging data that loaded.  So these staging tables are completely empty before the data load process begins.  Since that's the case, will indexes actually help or will they just slow things down?  And why would statistics be helpful if they are continually out of date?  We have about 30k records per table to process.  Our index rebuild / statistic update process only runs once per day, overnight.

Comment: Understanding your design, I still recommend the steps I've outlined above. My gut feel is that non-clustered indexes won't help, but that can only be confirmed by understanding your joins and data volumes. You do need to rethink your index/statistics process. Separate these concepts. Only build indexes when they are needed to improve the performance of a specific query. ALWAYS build statistics for a table after creating/updating it ... they're critical to performance, because they tell the optimiser where your data is, and how much  needs to be moved between nodes for optimum performance.

Comment: Good guidance here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-statistics

Answer (score 0):

Some input from my side - 
Your fact table should be partitioned . in fact you should have a job which creates the partitions in fact automatically . 
how big is fact table ? if your fact table is becoming too big then based on your requirement you can think of introducing archiving of old table if its not required in fact table .